# How do you separate integers into two separate variables?

Tags: vb.net, integer

I encountered a problem with my code. I made a program which asks the user(s) to enter a 'number of days' which is then separated into weeks and remainder of days.

Here is the code I've written so far (please click the link because I have not been given permission to post images yet):

[image: *http://imgur.com/fJB2dze*]

Some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, this question needs changes to avoid being closed as off-topic. 1) Please post actual, relevant, code, not images. 2) Please tell us what exactly the error is (posting any exception messages is good) 3) Please tell us what the code is supposed to do. For more information on how to ask a good question, you can refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx

Comment: Post code as code not as an image. See [ask], specifically [mcve].

Comment: `weeks = days \ 7 days = days - (weeks * 7)`

Comment: `weeks = inputDays / 7` and `remainingDays = inputDays  mod 7`; I don't know what you expect form the `if days/7 then` So as Peter Buins give you the Mod Operator documentation. I raise with [If documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx). `If` take a condition! Citation: "Condition
Required. Expression. Must evaluate to True or False, or to a data type that is implicitly convertible to Boolean."

Comment: Bonus: Read the error message! Value type of `Int` cannot be converted to `Boolean` mean Something is a int when Vb is expecting a bool. The line of the error should have help you find the error.

Comment: I'm new to Stackoverflow. Forgive me for my minor errors. I didn't know you could post code as images.

Comment: How do post the source code correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if is wrong and if the number of days >= 7 days will need to be recomputed.

```
    Dim weeks As Integer
    Dim days As Integer
    '....
    weeks = days \ 7
    If days >= 7 Then
        days = days - (weeks * 7)
        '...
    End If
```

Comment: I understand. I forgot to write the final bit of arithmetic and, of course, the IF statement was very wrong. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I agree the if statement is incorrect.   I am just adding another way to accomplish the same thing in case people are interested.

```
Dim weeks As Integer = 0
Dim days As Integer = 0
'...
If days >= 7 Then
    weeks = days / 7
    days = days % 7
   '...
End If
```